# $F = ma$, instantaneous Vs average

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

Are $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{a}$, in $\vec{F}=m \vec{a}$ instantaneous or average values (with respect to time)?

As F=ma is short for change in momentum/time, surely $a$ is an average?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140669/discussion-on-question-by-mathguy-f-ma-instantaneous-vs-average).

Answer (score 5):

They are instantaneous values.